# Importing a SVN repo is stuck at "Importing 0.00% Complete" in Phabricator

Tags: svn, phabricator

I am trying to setup Phabricator for code review at my company where most people are familiar with Microsoft technologies.

I installed Phabricator in a ubuntu virtual machine in VirtualBox. I imported our SVN repo which has a link like this `https://192.168.0.110/svn/FHT360`. However, it has been stuck at this page for more than 2 hours already and has made zero progress.

[image]

I tried Phabricator's IRC for help but there was nobody there. My only suspect is that Phabricator does not support HTTP for SVN yet (only SSH is supported). But why didn't it show an error when I added a HTTP link? (I can only do HTTP right now as the repo was setup by some else.)

[Update]

If I run `bin/phd status` I can see four `PhabricatorTaskmasterDaemon` running. However, in the web console, I see something like this for all of the four daemons:

```
Daemon 12 PhabricatorTaskmasterDaemon
This daemon encountered an error recently and is waiting a moment to restart.
Fri, Dec 12, 3:32 PM
Waiting
```

[image]

This was after I waited for about 20 minutes. Of course, it still shows `Importing  0.00% Complete`

Comment: HTTP is supported for svn. 

Look under Applications / Administration / Daemons to see where things are being held up.

Comment: @JSON Thanks. I tried what you suggested. Please see the [Update] portion of my post.

Comment: @JSON Thanks. You pointed me to the right direction. I didn't click into one of the daemons just now. There is actually stack trace inside it. The error message says **Define 'phabricator.base-uri' in your configuration to continue** and I fixed it.